# Woocomerce Dashboard to user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dashboard

Is there a way for the user to have a dashboard to able to add/edit products, view reports and orders of his store without access to WordPress admin?

i don't need to let him access to WordPress panel or admin panel to do that. so am checking if there is a customized dashboard for that

Comment: is it a multi vendor type? multi stores?

Comment: no only one store.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, your issue will be solved, [WordPress User Role and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) and [WooCommerce Shop Manager role and capabilities](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/roles-capabilities/#:%7E:text=Shop%20Manager%20role,%2C%20and%20create%2Fedit%20products.)

Just create another `user` and restrict it's access permission  from your `admin`.

He will just manage the products with a customized dashboard only what you'll allow.

Comment: I did this. i thought it should work, but somehow he still can access everything as admin !! there is a plugin i have to install?

Comment: There are some ways to prevent it through WordPress built-in features, however, if it's not clear to you, simply you can install a plugin, you can try Dokan plugin, it has a wide range of settings for accessing a store.

Comment: yea I know the role manager plugin. but I thought maybe there is a customized dashboard for the user in woocomerce. same dokan dashboard. but it seems there's not right?